# rawQuery on "count(*)" return no row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to fix a DB issue I had in Ankidroid. The following statement was executed:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM cards c WHERE type = 1 AND combinedDue <
1335153600.000000
```

It was generated [there](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/maintenance_1.1/src/com/ichi2/anki/Deck.java#L1626). The code executed is the following ([github link](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/maintenance_1.1/src/com/ichi2/anki/AnkiDb.java#L127)):

```
cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
  throw new SQLException("No result for query: " + query);
}
```

I can't understand how I can get no record, I should get either 1 or 0. The call stack in the log was the following:

```
at com.ichi2.anki.Deck.rebuildRevCount(Deck.java:1351)
    Caused by: android.database.SQLException: No result for query: ……
at com.ichi2.anki.AnkiDb.queryScalar(AnkiDb.java:129)
at com.ichi2.anki.Deck._rebuildRevCount(Deck.java:1621)
```

Any idea?

In fact, I was more looking at a similar case. We have a table «Stats» with a column "global", in which there can be one global record and many daily records. If we don't find (a simple *select*) the global record, we create it. On my phone, it seems that sometime the global record is not found, so we create an additional one, which break things.
It really look like the case I showed above.

**Edit**:

I found why. In another thread, an AsyncTask closes the DB at the same time the query is being made (because a lot of processing triggered by the GUI is done asynchronously). And it returns a cursor with no record.

I saw that by adding traces to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (cursor.moveToFirst == false)` instead of using the ! operator.  I think that the way you are currently doing it is always going to.pass you into the body of the if.  And the cursor isn' t properly initialized.without a.moveToFirst.

Comment: +1 .. it is also more "standard" and readable way of doing this IMHO

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I won't know immediately because it happens at best once a day. Anyway, that' strange because _rawQuery_ is supposed to return a cursor at position -1, but for the moment that's the best shot I have.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not reproduce the first case (with the count(*)). I could get the one I use to have once a day, in which a record cannot be found (using moveToFirst). I added some logging to a file to find in which circumstances. I'll let you know as soon as I have some info.